# c++ GetCursorPos issue

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to use c++ function GetCursorPos, but visual c++ 2010 gives me error:

```
1>click program.obj : error LNK2028: Nicht aufgelöstes Token (0A00001E) ""extern "C" int __stdcall GetCursorPos(struct tagPOINT *)" (?GetCursorPos@@$$J14YGHPAUtagPOINT@@@Z)", auf das in Funktion ""int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)" verwiesen wird.
1>click program.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""extern "C" int __stdcall GetCursorPos(struct tagPOINT *)" (?GetCursorPos@@$$J14YGHPAUtagPOINT@@@Z)" in Funktion ""int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)".
1>c:\users\maxwin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\click program\Debug\click program.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 nicht aufgelöste externe Verweise.
```

Google told me to do this:

```
Rightlick on the project in the solution explorer.
Select Linker
Select Input
Add User32.lib into the field "Additional Libraries"
```

But I failed to follow it, where is the solution explorer? Was this mb from a different compiler? I have visual c++ 2010 express.

Comment: i can't read German, could you provide a translation pls? :)

Answer (score 1):

The Solution Explorer is the tree that shows the files in your solution. It's usually on the right side of the code editor window. In VS2008 (with a Delphi Prism sample solution open), it looks like this:

[image: Solution Explorer Window iage]

In this image, you would right-click on **ConsoleApplication1** and choose **Properties**, and then follow the directions above.